# simple procedural maths program in C#

Tags: c#, average

so I am creating a very simple program in C# (my first one).
It should do an average of X numbers.. instead of writing it all out manually, it'll be much better done procedurally (I'm not sure if that's even a word). Basically as I've done with the 'amount' in the example below. I could just divide it by 2 (in this case). But instead I have a variable that increases with each new entry - so the program would work regardless of how many entries there are.

The same thing I'd need to do with the variables 'first', 'second' etc. I need some variable that would change dynamically, based on the number of entries. This should be a peace of cake algorithm-wise but this is my first day with C# and I can't manage to do it (namely because I am lacking the knowledge of syntax).

```
        double first;
        double second;
        int amount = 0;
        double result;

        Console.Write("Write your first number");
        first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ++amount; 

        Console.Write("Write your second number");
        second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ++amount;

        result = (first + second) / amount;

        Console.Write("The average of your numbers is: " + result);
```

Thanks

Comment: So other than needing a loop, what exactly is your question?

Comment: There is a question missing in your question, but I assume you're looking for a `do..while`/`while` loop.

Comment: @Mephy exactly, that's the one! Sorry, I couldn't think of the name... so what would that look like in C#?

Comment: If this is your first day with C#, maybe you should read more about it before asking questions. You'll learn way more if you try stuff by yourself than heading here with basic questions to get an easy answer.

Comment: To know what it would look like in C#, read [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx). It's there for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the gist of what I think you want. I'll use pseudocode to give you the opportunity to learn the C#:

```
create a list of numbers
output prompt
read input line

while the input line had a value
  parse the input value
  add the parsed value to the list of numbers
  output prompt
  read input line

calculate the sum of the values divided by the length of the list
output the calculated average
```

Comment: Instead of dealing with a list and totaling it later, you could just keep a running total. Not like you need to keep the numbers around.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: That is a valid approach, as well. In practice, I often find that code is easier to debug, unit test, maintain, and adapt to new requirements if I separate the collection of input from the calculations.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior exactly! This is what I need to do. But even with  a loop (as suggested in the comments above) I have some problems. The loop can only increment the length of the list. What I need is that every value would be dynamically assigned to a variable (a temporary container for one value at a time, just to perform the current addition).

Comment: @Mike94: That's a common misconception for developers who aren't used to working with data structures. *You don't need to create a new variable for every value*: once you have a list of numbers, you can simply call the LINQ `.Average()` extension method to calculate the average of the values in that list. Under the covers, that method uses a loop to keep a running total of the Sum (as Corey suggested), and then divides it by the list's length.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I looked at the LINQ extension methods a bit (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). Although I don't think I will be able to successfully implement it to my program, at least I know how I would theoretically deal with similar assignments in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after the recusive average?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Compute Average Recursively:

        int average_count = 0;
        double average = 0;

        average = RecursiveAverage(average, ref average_count, 1);
        average = RecursiveAverage(average, ref average_count, 2);
        average = RecursiveAverage(average, ref average_count, 3);
        average = RecursiveAverage(average, ref average_count, 4);

        Console.WriteLine(average); //2.5
    }

    private static double RecursiveAverage(double previous, ref int average_count, double next)
    {
        average_count += 1;
        return ((average_count - 1.0) / (average_count)) * previous + (1.0 / (average_count)) * next;
    }

}
```

See: http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/RecursiveStatistic/Time-Average.htm

Update: Keep updating the average indefinitely (or until average_count gets too large to store without a `BigInteger` ) without having to remember all the numbers...

```
while (true)
{
    var next = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    average = RecursiveAverage(average, ref average_count, next);
    Console.WriteLine("Average is now: " + average); 
}
```

Comment: Not exactly recursive average that I need here. Although this is a great example (and a very useful little program) so I'll try this one too. Thanks!

Comment: Why would he be after the recursive average? What advantage does this offer over any other, simpler solution?

Comment: I read the "average of X numbers" to imply an unknown number to average over. And given he is asking for user input; its not far to assume an unknown input size.

Comment: The code, as written, will only compute the average for 4 inputs.  For each additional input, you will have to add another line of code.  So the program would need to know the number of inputs at compile time.